# C# MAUI свернуть в трей приложение Windows

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Приложение на C# MAUI. Не могу найти решения как свернуть приложение в трей ОС Windows. Решения только для WinForms и WPF.
Свернуть с отображением в панели задач - без проблем:

```
private void doMinimize(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var Window = App.Current.Windows.First();
        var nativeWindow = Window.Handler.PlatformView;
        IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
        WindowId WindowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
        AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(WindowId);

        var p = appWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;

        p.Minimize();
}
```

Comment: Через WinAPI Interop только если. MAUI - кроссплатформенное приложение, там нет чисто виндовых фич, точнее есть, но далеко не все. Грубо говоря, можете покопаться в исходниках Winforms и выдернуть оттуда релизацию по работе с треем на низком уровне. Либо поискать готовое решение для MAUI в NuGet, если оно существует.